# Insert string at the beginning of each line

Tags: python, string, file

How can I insert a string at the beginning of each line in a text file, I have the following code:

```py
f = open('./ampo.txt', 'r+')
with open('./ampo.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        f.insert(0, 'EDF ')
f.close
```

I get the following error:

```
'file' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python comes with [batteries included](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput):

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(['./ampo.txt'], inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write('EDF {l}'.format(l=line))
```

Unlike the solutions already posted, this also preserves file permissions.

Comment: _"this also preserves file permissions"_ I didn't know. +1

Comment: this seem much better, thank you. can you explain a little whats going on?

Comment: The `for-loop` iterates over the lines in `ampo.txt` one line at a time. `sys.stdout.write` is almost the same as `print`. The reason I chose to use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print` is because `print` adds an extra newline, while `sys.stdout.write` does not. Because of the `inplace=True` argument, `fileinput` moves the original ampo.txt to a temporary file, then redirects stdout to a new file called `ampo.txt`. Then it copies permissions and removes the tempory file. There are more options, like keeping a backup file; see the docs for more info.

Comment: @unutbu , could this be adapted to only write on to a specified line? Such as line 3, for example.

Comment: @dantdj: Yes, you can use `if fileinput.filelineno() == 3:` to change the behavior depending on which line you are on.

Comment: This seems to remove the rest of the file, unfortunately. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/83KGFHBM) the program with the if statement added, in case I've done anything wrong. [This](http://pastebin.com/hRykSj1f) is the program I'm trying to change, to try and add a "#" to the start of line 3. Stack Overflow's link highlighting isn't too great, heh.

Comment: @dantdj: To modify a file you have to rewrite every line of that file. Think of a file as a chunk of memory. To insert one character in the middle, you have to write that character *and* scoot every successive character over by one. Following this same idea, your program would need look like [this](http://pastebin.com/xKR6fEVC).

Comment: @unutbu: Ah, should have seen that! Thanks for the help, it's greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 8):

You can't modify a file inplace like that. Files do not support insertion. You have to read it all in and then write it all out again.

You can do this line by line if you wish. But in that case you need to write to a temporary file and then replace the original. So, for small enough files, it is just simpler to do it in one go like this:

```
with open('./ampo.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines = ['EDF '+line for line in lines]
with open('./ampo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: I'd suggest either the lazy comprehension or even better adding the string as part of either the read or the write operation. That way the file content will be in memory only once, not twice.

Comment: @Jan Could you elaborate. I'm not 100% fluent in Python so I'd be interested to learn more from someone who clearly knows more than I.

Comment: The `[x for y in z]` form creates a new list object and the old one can't be garbage-collected until the new one is constructed, so at one point there are all the original strings and all the modified strings in memory at once. But there is also `(x for y in z)` form, which instead creates a generator. Generators are lazy; they execute the expression on one input value at a time and return it, so it can be collected before next one is needed and they are never in memory at the same time. In this case you have to be careful not to make it too lazy, since file also supports lazy read.

Comment: That is there are two options: `['EDF ' + line for line in open('./ampo.txt', 'r')]` uses generator to read the file lazily, but than evaluates the list eagerly to have the file wholly in memory before rewriting it. `('EDF ' + line for line in f.readlines())` uses the eager reading function to get the file in memory, but than generator to construct the modified text eagerly. Of course if you used generator for both, you'd burn yourself badly, because you'd start rewriting the file before getting all the data out of it.

Comment: Of course there is third option, using generators for both steps, but writing to a new file and than renaming that file over the original. That has the advantage of handling huge files (there is usually more space on disk than in memory) and not losing information if the process gets interrupted.

Comment: @Jan Your third option was mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it was. And as far as it goes, I would actually prefer it always, because of the "does not loose information if interrupted" part.

Answer (score 0):

For a file not too big:

```
with open('./ampo.txt', 'rb+') as f:
    x = f.read()
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.writelines(('EDF ', x.replace('\n','\nEDF ')))
    f.truncate()
```

Note that , IN THEORY, in THIS case (the content is augmented), the `f.truncate()` may be not really necessary. Because the with statement is supposed to close the file correctly, that is to say, writing an EOF (end of file ) at the end before closing.
That's what I observed on examples.
But I am prudent: I think it's better to put this instruction anyway. For when the content diminishes, the with statement doesn't write an EOF to close correctly the file less far than the preceding initial EOF, hence trailing initial characters remains in the file.
So if the with statement doens't write EOF when the content diminishes, why would it write it when the content augments ?

For a big file, to avoid to put all the content of the file in RAM at once:

```
import os

def addsomething(filepath, ss):
    if filepath.rfind('.') > filepath.rfind(os.sep):
        a,_,c = filepath.rpartition('.')
        tempi = a + 'temp.' + c
    else:
        tempi = filepath + 'temp'

    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f, open(tempi,'wb') as g:
        g.writelines(ss + line for line in f)

    os.remove(filepath)
    os.rename(tempi,filepath)


addsomething('./ampo.txt','WZE')
```

Comment: Do note that this will overwrite your file in-place. Additionally you have to **make sure** that you know everything you're going to write before you start writing; an exception during writing will produce a corrupted file. (This answer does have that issue because python is greedily evaluated.)

Comment: @ninjagecko: There are many, many things in python that are **not** eagerly evaluated.

Comment: @eyquem: what is the purpose of `f.truncate()`?

Comment: @unutbu Here, **f.truncate()** is useless because the resulting content is longer than the former one in the file. But I put it anyway to make readers conscious that it is necessary in other cases, that is to say when the content diminishes. I was surprised that the with statement didn't write an EOF (end of file) character before closing a file, once in a program I did: there were still the trailing characters of the initial content until the former EOF after the treatment.

Comment: @ninjagecko Good idea. But I don't understand the last sentence: what is greedily evaluated ? (it's not Python) And what consequence ? I don't see the point

Comment: @unutbu I correct my idea. **f.truncate()** SEEMS to be useless in this case. But that's only on examples. I'm not sure it will work in all the cases (see what I add in my answer). So I think it's preferable to put it anyway

Comment: @JanHudec: what are some examples?

Comment: @ninjagecko: The two kinds of generators (generator comprehension and function using `yield`) and all the things that return one from their `__iter__()` method (like `file`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution where you write to a temporary file and move it into place.  You might prefer this version if the file you are rewriting is very large, since it avoids keeping the contents of the file in memory, as versions that involve `.read()` or `.readlines()` will.  In addition, if there is any error in reading or writing, your original file will be safe:

```
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

filename = './ampo.txt'
tmp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
with open(filename) as finput:
    with open(tmp.name, 'w') as ftmp:
        for line in finput:
            ftmp.write('EDF '+line)
move(tmp.name, filename)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open('./ampo.txt', 'r')
lines = map(lambda l : 'EDF ' + l, f.readlines())
f.close()
f = open('./ampo.txt', 'w')
map(lambda l : f.write(l), lines)
f.close()
```

Comment: -1: You missed the part where the file needs to be written back!

Comment: Still -1: Using `map` where you should have used comprehension in one case and loop in the other is not good python style.