# How to turn newlines in a file to lines extending to end of line?

Tags: python

I am copying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633485/insert-string-at-the-beginning-of-each-line/7633962#7633962) like this

```
for line in fileinput.input(['my_file'], inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write('_____ {l}'.format(l=line))
```

to add four underlines to beginning of line. This turns `my_file` into a checklist. But the above code prints the underlines on the blank lines too. I want to change the blank lines to full length lines. How do I do that? So if the original lines are like this

```
abc

def

ghi
```

the checklist will look like

```
___ abc

_________________________________________________

___ def

_________________________________________________

___ ghi

_________________________________________________
```

---

Thanks!

Comment: What determines the length of a line?

Comment: @kojiro: best would be going to the margin but a fixed line length is ok too.

Comment: but you don't seem to have specified a margin.

Comment: @kojiro, ok, I thought printer set the margins. Can I set them in the code?

Comment: You can set line *length* in the code. I was just trying to point out that unless you know how long a line is, you can't print characters to the end of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip the whitespace on the line and see if it's non-empty (and thus, truthy). If it's non-empty, do what it did before. Otherwise, it's empty; print the horizontal line. (although I must say 49 characters is somewhat odd)

```
term_width = 50
with contextlib.closing(fileinput.input(['my_file'], inplace=True)) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            sys.stdout.write('_____ {l}'.format(l=line))
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('\n'.rjust(term_width, '_'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting `RuntimeError: input() already active`. According to this page http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-August/037593.html means "you've called
fileinput.input() before, but then you didn't consume all the lines
available." How can I fix this?

Comment: @Zeynel: I don't get that error, but I'm guessing you have `fileinput.input` somewhere else in your program that hasn't finished.

Comment: yes, I restarted IDLE and it worked but the second time I tried I got the same error. How can I finish fileinput.input after each time?

Comment: Now I get windows error: File "C:\Python26\lib\fileinput.py", line 322, in readline
    os.rename(self._filename, self._backupfilename)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @Zeynel: And you're sure the file exists when you get that error?

Comment: yes, `myfile` exists but I was wondering if there is a simpler way to achieve the same result that I can understand. thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel: I don't know why it's not working then. Sorry. If you didn't need to change the file in-place, you could `open` two files and read from one and write to the other, which might be simpler.