# How to write to file in different places?

Tags: python

I want to

1. open file
2. add 4 underline character to beginning of line
3. find blank lines
4. replace the newline character in the blank lines with 50 underline characters
5. add new lines before and after 50 underline characters

I found many similar questions in stackoverflow but I could not combine all these operations without getting errors. [See my previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844477/how-to-turn-newlines-in-a-file-to-lines-extending-to-end-of-line). Is there a simple beginners way to accomplish this so that I can start from there? (I don't mind writing to the same file; there is no need to open two files) Thanks.

Comment: This is the same question you asked before. _Update_ that question with more info / clearer meaning, don't ask a new, duplicate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn newlines in a file to lines extending to end of line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844477/how-to-turn-newlines-in-a-file-to-lines-extending-to-end-of-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to pick:

- Use two files, but never have to store more than 1 line in memory at a time
  **or**
- Build the new file in memory as you read the original, then overwrite the original with the new

A file isn't a flexible memory structure. You can't replace the 1 or 2 characters from a newline with 50 underscores, it just doesn't work like that. If you are sure the new file is going to be a manageable size **and** you don't mind writing over the original, you can do it without having a new file.

Myself, I would **always** allow the user to opt for an output file. What if something goes wrong? Disk space is super cheap.

Comment: Ok, I see, but I cannot make the writing the underscore characters to the output file in my previous question. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do everything you want reading the file first, performing the changes on the lines, and finally writing it back. If the file doesn't fit in memory, then you should read the file in batches and create an temporal file. You can't modify the file in situ.

Comment: +1. More specifically: when you write to the beginning of a file, you simply overwrite what was there without making everything already in the file "move down" to a later position in the file.

Comment: It is possible to modify a file in-situ, just not to insert data (only overwrite or append it).

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I misunderstood the process. Any suggestions or examples for me to try? Thanks.

Comment: Open the file, use readlines(). That will give you a list of the lines that you can modify, or insert new sutff, etc. Then write them back. If you're going to write to the same file at the end, open it in "rw" mode.