# Append same text to every line of a file in python

Tags: python

I have a file in this pattern:

```
    Y2.249 Z283.923 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0 
    Y2.758 Z283.731 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0
```

I need to append the characters GOTO/ before every line of the file. How do I do that? Here is my code

```
def main():
     file=open("orig.txt","r")
     lines=file.readlines()
     file.close()
     for line in lines:
     line=line.strip()
     print(line)
main()
```

Comment: `print("GOTO/" + line)`?

Comment: `print('GOTO/{}'.format(line))` ? Is that what you want?

Comment: Do you just want to print the modified lines, or do you want to save them to a new file?

Comment: Yes got it thanks. @BurhanKhalid it works but adds a space between every line so this is precise   print("GOTO/{}".format(line[:-1]))

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def main():
     with open("orig.txt","r") as in_file:
         lines=in_file.readlines()

     out_lines = ["GOTO/{}\n".format(line.strip()) for line in lines]

     with open("new.txt", "w") as out_file:
         out_file.writelines(out_lines)

main()
```

You will find the modified content in `new.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you

[Insert string at the beginning of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633485/insert-string-at-the-beginning-of-each-line)

```
 with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    lines = ['GOTO '+line for line in lines]
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```