# Overwriting lines in text file

Tags: python, file

I want to overwrite lines in a file without losing the data. The program starts by writing data separated by tabs into a "students2.txt" file.

```
filename = "students2.txt"
file_write = open(filename, "a")

num_of_students = int(input("Enter number of students: "))
for i in range(1, num_of_students + 1):
    print("Student", i)
    first_name = input("Enter your first name: ")
    last_name = input("Enter your last name: ")
    matric_no = input("Enter your matric number: ")
    print("Input attendance")
    mar_4 = int(input())
    mar_11 = int(input())
    mar_18 = int(input())
    mar_25 = int(input())
    file_write.write(first_name.title() + "\t")

    file_write.write(last_name.title() + "\t")
    file_write.write(matric_no.upper() + "\t")
    file_write.write(str(mar_4) + "\t")
    file_write.write(str(mar_11) + "\t")
    file_write.write(str(mar_25) + "\t")
    file_write.write(str(mar_18) + "\t" + "\n")
file_write.close()
```

Then it reads from that file and performs some calculations

```
file_read = open("students2.txt", "r")
file_write = open("students2.txt", "a")
for i in file_read.readlines():
    i = i.strip().split()
    std_sum = int(i[3]) + int(i[4]) + int(i[5]) + int(i[6])
    std_attd_percent = (std_sum/4) * 100
    file_write.write(str(std_attd_percent))
```

I want to write the std_attd_percent to each line of the "student2.txt" but it just writes it all to the end of the line.

Comment: This link should do the job : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633485/insert-string-at-the-beginning-of-each-line

Comment: @Barmar: Right — comment deleted.

Comment: file_obj = open("students2.txt", "r+")
data =  file_obj.readlines()


for line_no in range(0,len(data)) :
    i = data[line_no][:].strip().split()
    std_sum = int(i[3]) + int(i[4]) + int(i[5]) + int(i[6])
    std_attd_percent = (std_sum / 4) * 100
    data[line_no] = data[line_no][:(len(data[line_no])-1)]+ f'\t{std_attd_percent}'
    print( data[line_no] )